# Microsoft Edge: How do I prevent the "You've updated Microsoft Edge" tab from appearing whenever Edge updates itself?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Whenever Microsoft Edge updates itself, it opens a tab alerting me to the fact that it has been updated (pictured below). This happens the first time I launch the browser after the updates have been installed.

I administer public access computers and would like to prevent this tab from appearing. Is this possible?

I have the group policy settings installed. The only setting I could find is "Hide the First-run experience and splash screen", but Enabling that setting does not help.

(This question has been cross-posted on the [Microsoft Community forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_open-msedge_win10/how-do-you-prevent-the-youve-updated-microsoft/07eff525-2904-458b-b219-d5c5d26065ef?tm=1619096984629))

[image: Screenshot of "Here's what's new" page]